# Error “Not authorised to send Apple events to Terminal.” when starting Maxima

Tags: terminal, mojave, automation, privacy

I downloaded [Maxima](https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/) and installed on Mac OS Mojave (10.14.6).
I followed instructions and remove the quanrantine attributes :

```bsh
$ sudo xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Maxima.app
```

but then I get error “*Not authorised to send Apple events to Terminal.*” :

[image]

The reason is *Maxima.app* try to launch UI (*Maxima*, *Rmaxima*, or *wxMaxima*) through *Terminal.app*.
This error is known, but I did not find any answer, for instance the topic “[How fix macOS Catalina error “not authorized to send apple events to terminal”?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250844626)” is unanswered.

A solution is given (for a different but close problem) in “[Mojave: not authorized to send Apple events](https://applehelpwriter.com/2018/09/24/mojave-not-authorized-to-send-apple-events/)” : allowing *Terminal* to the *Full Disk Access* in `Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access`.
Howewer, *Maxima.app* need to launch *Terminal.app*, so I think I have to authorise *Maxima.app* to control *Terminal.app* in `Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation`, but I can not add *Maxima.app* (there is no “`+`” button !) :

[image]

A related stackoverflow topic already exists : [macOS Mojave, Automator “Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299066), but no answers solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, tried the things in the link.  Eventually this is what worked for me:

1. Open `Terminal.app`
2. Navigate to the `Maxima.app/contents/MacOS/ folder:

   ```
   % cd /Applications/Maxima.app/Contents/MacOS
   ```
3. Run the `applet` binary:

   ```
   % ./applet
   ```
4. This finally triggered the pop-up requesting access.  Click to allow access.